# vb6 listbox list timer

Tags: vb6, listbox

i want to iterate listbox list item with Timer1 .

for example, if listbox list item have 'A','B','C'

then i want to make run 'A' then run timer1

and after finish 'B' then run timer1 and so on

maybe this is easy for someone but it not easy for me because Timer1 is continue looping

and it make me some confused.

sorry my bad english and anyone could enlight me i really much appreate!

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()   
    For xx = 0 To List3.listcount - 1
      Timer1.Enabled = True
    Next xx
End Sub

Public Sub Timer1_Timer()
some code....
.
.
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not thinking of the timer correctly. VB6 runs code synchronously in general so if you just run 'A' under normal circumstances control will not return from 'A' until 'A' is finished at which time you can start 'B'. If you only want to run 'A', then 'B', then 'C' all you should need to do it run them one after another.

Answer (score 0):

The `Timer1_Timer()` event fires every interval of the timer - so your code needs to go in there.

Something like this (untested code):

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()   
    Timer1.Enabled = True ' Start the timer
End Sub

Public Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Static currentIndex = 0
    ' Do what you want with List1.List(currentIndex)
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
    If (currentIndex = List1.ListCount) Then
         Timer1.Enabled = False ' Stop the timer
    End if
End Sub
```

The `Interval` property of `Timer1` controls how often `Timer1_Timer()` is called.